401 Unauthorized Error during token refresh API call
I can't solve the implementation of refresh tokens, my backend is OK at PostMan works OK, with a curl command it's OK too, I send the header with a refresh token and the backend responses with an object with an accessToken that works ok too, but when I use the frontend the error is a 401! Please help me.!
This is the Interceptor:
export const customInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
    const excludedRoutes = ['/login']; // Customizable array
    const shouldExclude = excludedRoutes.some(route => req.url.includes(route));
    const authService = inject(AuthService);

    if (shouldExclude) {
        return next(req);
    }

    const token = authService.getAuthToken();
    const cloneRequest = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    });

    return next(cloneRequest).pipe(
        catchError((error) => {
            if (error.status === 401) {
                console.log("From the interceptor, here is the error: " + error.status);
                return authService.refreshToken().pipe(
                    switchMap((res) => {
                        localStorage.setItem('authToken', res.accessToken);
                        console.log("From the interceptor, the new authToken is: " + res.accessToken);
                        const newReq = req.clone({
                            setHeaders: {
                                Authorization: `Bearer ${res.accessToken}`
                            }
                        });

                        return next(newReq);
                    }),
                    catchError((refreshErr) => {
                        const finalError = new Error(refreshErr);
                        console.log("Error refreshing the token", finalError);
                        authService.logout();
                        return throwError(() => new Error('Session expired, please log in again'));
                    })
                );
            } else {
                // Handle other errors (e.g., network errors)
                return throwError(() => error);
            }
        })
    );
};

This is the service method:
refreshToken() {
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refreshToken');
    console.log("The refreshToken inside the method is: " + refreshToken);

    if (!refreshToken) {
        throw new Error('Refresh token missing');
    }
    
    console.log("Sending refresh token to backend: " + refreshToken);
    
    return this._httpClient.post<any>(`${this.baseURL}/refresh`, {}, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${refreshToken}`
        }
    }).pipe(
        catchError((error) => {
            console.error("Refresh token error:", error);
            return throwError(() => new Error("Refresh error"));
        })
    );
}


Open the network tab in your browser and find out what's different about the request compared to your Postman or curl request (request headers, params, ...)

You should add path '/refresh' to your excludedRoutes array. Now outdated access token is being added to /refresh request, it may be the reason of 401

Thanks a lot leonmain, you're right! It'works perfect now!

"You should add path '/refresh' to your excludedRoutes array. Now outdated access token is being added to /refresh request, it may be the reason of 401 –
leonmain"
Commented yesterday
Solved my problem, thanks for all!!!

Please mark this answer as the correct answer if it correctly answered your question :)

It seems like your customInterceptor is mostly set up correctly, but there might be a few reasons why you're getting a 401 error in your Angular frontend:
Token Synchronization Issue: There might be an issue where the interceptor tries to use the old token even after getting the new one.
Interceptor Chaining Issue: If multiple interceptors are registered, they may not handle the 401 error correctly, causing the token refresh to not propagate properly.
API Request Timing: The token refresh might not have completed before the new request is made.
Angular's HttpInterceptorFn Syntax: If you are using Angular 16+ with the HttpInterceptorFn function type, ensure the setup is correctly implemented.
tried this code :
export const customInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
    const excludedRoutes = ['/login']; // Exclude login endpoint from interception
    const shouldExclude = excludedRoutes.some(route => req.url.includes(route));
    const authService = inject(AuthService);

    if (shouldExclude) {
        return next(req);
    }

    const token = authService.getAuthToken();
    let cloneRequest = req;

    if (token) {
        cloneRequest = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        });
    }

    return next(cloneRequest).pipe(
        catchError((error) => {
            if (error.status === 401) {
                // Token is expired or invalid, try refreshing the token
                return authService.refreshToken().pipe(
                    switchMap((res) => {
                        // Store new access token
                        localStorage.setItem('authToken', res.accessToken);

                        // Clone the request with new token and resend it
                        const newReq = req.clone({
                            setHeaders: {
                                Authorization: `Bearer ${res.accessToken}`
                            }
                        });

                        // Continue the request with the new token
                        return next(newReq);
                    }),
                    catchError((refreshErr) => {
                        // Refresh token failed, handle logout or other error
                        console.log("Error refreshing the token:", refreshErr);
                        authService.logout(); // Redirect to login or handle logout
                        return throwError(() => new Error('Session expired, please log in again'));
                    })
                );
            } else {
                // For any other errors
                return throwError(() => error);
            }
        })
    );
};

In authService :
refreshToken() {
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refreshToken');
    console.log("The refreshToken inside the method is: " + refreshToken);

    if (!refreshToken) {
        throw new Error('Refresh token missing');
    }
    
    return this._httpClient.post<any>(`${this.baseURL}/refresh`, {}, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${refreshToken}`
        }
    }).pipe(
        catchError((error) => {
            console.error("Refresh token error:", error);
            return throwError(() => new Error("Refresh error"));
        })
    );
}


Thanks, Fisherman! It didn't work, but I really appreciate your help! When I try using Postman, everything works fine, but my Angular frontend doesn’t refresh the token. I'm not using any other interceptors.

You should use an interceptor, it's really useful and easy to do. I already have similar problems. If with an interceptor the problem is still there, then you'll have to look elsewhere.

This code is a Custom Interceptor, I've solved the issue excluding the path '/refresh'. Thanks a lot for your answer!

So glad you were able to solve your problem!
